# Is Rumpelstiltskin’s name Rumpel Stiltskin in Shrek?

Tags: shrek

I’m asking, because people call him “Rumpel” or “Mr. Stiltskin” and Shrek calls him “Stiltskin.”

Answer (score 4):

The credits for the film list his name as *"Rumpelstiltskin"* (all one word)

[image]

As does the DVD box cover for the film.

[image]

His desire to go by "Mr Stilstkin / Rumpel" may be a call-back to [earlier myths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumpelstiltskin) where going around telling people his *full name* would be undesirable.